# Sysprep needing to validate Windows when selecting generalize

Tags: windows-11, windows-activation, sysprep

I've been trying to create a WIM of my modified Windows 11 install. To that end, I've been attempting to have Sysprep clean Win 11 using the "generalize" option. Yet, in Sysprep, every time I tick "generalize" & click OK, a dialog saying "Sysprep was not able to validate your Windows installation" pops up.

This doesn't seem to be the case as checking System > Activation > Activation state says it's "Active". It seems like the license for the OEM Win 10 this laptop came with carried over for Win 11.

So far, every once in a while, I've been able to trigger a reboot/shutdown with generalize when I use tools that disrupts the activation state of Windows, like say, running KMSpico or manually entering a different product key.

I need a way to be able to reboot/shutdown with generalize selected without these fickle tricks of disrupting the activation state.

Comment: Just to clarify, Windows 10 OEM licenses, are able to activate OEM installations of Windows 11.

Comment: Very little without the setupact.log file that was generated.  The reason Windows was unable to validate (which has nothing to do with the activation status of Windows) will be specified in the log file.  By the tone of your last comment, I can tell you don't find my comment very helpful, which makes me very cautious asking for additional information since I have no idea how you will react to additional questions about your problem.

Comment: Here's a copy of the setupact.log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LXFq4OiWPhy9fMNy8_ysr4HCLbUnNwkG/view

Comment: It's been **4 hours**.  When I have the time I will look at it the logs, **if** I see something, I will submit an answer.  If there is a problem with that timeline, then I can just skip that last part, and enjoy my night.

Comment: “Microsoft.OneDriveSync_21220.1024.5.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.” - This is the error that cause the “cannot validate” error.

Comment: Using the same user you ran sysprep on before run, *Get-AppXPackage -AllUser | % {if ($_.PackageUserInformation.InstallState -eq "Staged"){$_.PackageFullname}}*, and provide the output to that command as an edit to your question

Comment: One of the first thing I did in the previous install is uninstalling One Drive. Now I'm working on another install. I won't touch it & try to keep a look out for it & the log file.

Comment: You lost me on the _Get-AppXPackage_ thing...

Comment: So it sounds like you will be unable to provide me the output of that command from the exact installation that generated that sysprep error, without that error, I cannot diagnose the problem.  You might think you uninstalled One Drive, but the error in your own logs, say otherwise and you’re not alone. I have the researched to answer your question once I have the data I need to do so. I will be notified of changes to your question no need to ping me.

Comment: I've been trying to run Sysprep again, with same results. The only difference is that setupact.log is still new & short: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNB-yzeSMVf5KgsZaA0rXrU32IZsjs5a/view

Comment: Your new log still has the same error. I really need the output of that command.

Comment: Which file would have that? setuperr.log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139315/discussion-between-ramhound-and-tempus-nomen).

Answer (score 0):

> To that end, I've been attempting to have Sysprep clean Win 11 using the "generalize" option. Yet, in Sysprep, every time I tick "generalize" & click OK, a dialog saying "Sysprep was not able to validate your Windows installation" pops up.
>
> `Error: SYSPRP Package Microsoft.OneDriveSync_21220.1024.5.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.`

The log you provided indicates that *Microsoft.OneDriveSync* was the reason Windows wasn’t able to be validated.

Run the following commands as an Administrator in a PowerShell prompt:

> Import-Module Appx
>
> Import-Module Dism
>
> Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.OneDriveSync_21220.1024.5.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
>
> Remove-AppxPackage -Package Microsoft.OneDriveSync_21220.1024.5.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
>
> Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where PublisherId -eq 8wekyb3d8bbwe | Format-List -Property PackageFullName,PackageUserInformation

For each application from the last command run the following:

> Remove-AppxPackage -Package <packagefullname>
>
> Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName

Source:

- [Sysprep fails after you remove or update Microsoft Store apps that include built-in Windows images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/sysprep-fails-remove-or-update-store-apps#resolution)
- [Errors when capturing Windows 11 image by using capture media in Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/windows-11-image-capture-fail#packagenotprovisionedforallusers)