# Cannot boot after Sysprep with generalize & reboot/shutdown selected

Tags: boot, windows-11, sysprep

I've gotten through some roadblocks with a good amount of help, & now I can execute Sysprep with generalize & shutdown/reboot: [Sysprep needing to validate Windows when selecting generalize](https://superuser.com/questions/1743127/sysprep-needing-to-validate-windows-when-selecting-generalize).

The problem is, when Windows tries to boot after, it gets stuck in "Getting ready", as if reconfiguring Windows for the first time use. Then it will show a dialog box to the effect of "the windows installation unexpectedly rebooted or something went wrong. Click OK to reboot & restart the installation again" (paraphrased).

How do I get past this getting stuck in boot time? It's not like I can pull up the log files now that I'm stuck at booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

- When getting the message "The computer restarted unexpectedly",
  do not click OK
- Press Shift+F10 to invoke a command prompt
- Type `regedit` and press Enter
- Navigate the registry to :
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\ChildCompletion`
- Double-click `setup.exe` on the right
- Change the value from `1` to `3` and click OK to save changes
- Close `regedit`
- Reboot using the command `shutdown -r -t 0`
- If system unstable, reboot again.

Comment: I just did as you told. Then it rebooted & now it's stuck on "Just a moment..." Doing a Shift+F10 doesn't seem to work here. Help?

Comment: Actually, at this point, Shift+F10 does open the cmd. You can even Alt+Tab it. It's just permanently covered behind a black foreground, the "Just a moment" text & the progress wheel.